# Validation Error in Lightswitch with RegEx

Tags: regex, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have a property that is NIF, and is like SSN but in Spain and the format can be:

```
A0000000A  
00000000A  
A00000000
```

Where **A** stands for **Alphanumeric** and **0** for **Digits**. In any case it must be 9 characters.

Using Visual Studio 2013 LightSwitch I try to validate it using RegEx.
The regular expression I wrote for this case is

```
^\b\w\d{7}\w\b$
```

and I have tested in several webs, and so far, the RegEx works.

But when I run the app put a valid data it doesn't work and the validation error appears on screen.
Here is the validation code:

```
Private Sub NIF_Validate(results As EntityValidationResultsBuilder)

    Dim pattern As String = "^\b\w\d{7}\w\b$"

    If (NIF IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (Not Regex.IsMatch(pattern, NIF)) Then
            results.AddPropertyError("Check NIF")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after many hours reviewing the code I found the error. Its in `Regex.IsMatch` where the first parameter must be the text and the second one the pattern.

```
Regex.IsMatch(input As String, pattern As String)
```

Thanks for the answers. And sorry for the silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is the escape character in strings. Therefore you need to define the pattern string as

```
"^\\b\\w\\d{7}\\w\\b$"
```

whereby `\\b` respectively `\b` is here twice not really needed because of `^` and `$`.

The regular expression string defined by your Visual Basic code as interpreted is `^bwd{7}wb$`.